# Problems with a RPG Distinct and Join SQL statement

Tags: sql, join, ibm-midrange, db2-400

I have two databases that I am trying to join and get the distinct values from.  One table contains a list of items on order and the other type contains more information about the item. I am only using the Join to do an additional where statement check. The problem is that it does not seem to adhere to the where statement check from the item details file if that value changes while the SQL statement is running and after the cursor has been opened.

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    OrdItem                                            
FROM
    OrdMst 
INNER JOIN 
    ItmMst ON OrdMst.OrdItem = ItmMst.Item              
WHERE 
    OrdMst.ID = 'MR' 
    AND OrdMst.TYPE = 'F' 
    AND ItmMst.ItmType IN ('1', '2') 
ORDER BY 
    OrdMst.OrdItem;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's better to think of any single database statement as an instantaneous activity.  The database collects up all results and gives you a cursor so you can iterate through those results (e.g. see the select section [here](https://malisper.me/postgres-transactions-arent-fully-isolated/)).  In postgres (and I would assume by default elsewhere), the result set isn't mutating along with the database.  [DB2](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPEK_11.0.0/sqlref/src/tpc/db2z_sql_declarecursor.html) users should see the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58227956/1978687) from @Charles (below) as DB2 apparently supports mutating results.

Please note that most database packages use "lazy" evaluation of result sets.  This lets you do things like add conditions and ordering statements without repeatedly evaluating the query.  If you think you are seeing mutation, it's probably due to the delayed execution of your query.

We don't generally expect/want the database to work differently.  As a simple example of why, imagine a case where you're operating on records.  You select records and order by last_modified.  You do something to the record and updated last_modified.  If the recordset mutated, the operation would never complete as you'd keep sticking the thing you modified at the end of the recordset.

What are you trying to achieve that isn't working because the recordset isn't mutating?  You're better off asking how to achieve that goal in light of the unchanging database (we call this the [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)).

Comment: No real problem trying to solve was just testing a program and notice this occurrence.  What puzzled me was if I add the ItmMst.ItmType to the field selection list then it behaves normally.

    SELECT DISTINCT 
        OrdItem, ItmMst.ItmType                                            
    FROM
        OrdMst 
    INNER JOIN 
        ItmMst ON OrdMst.OrdItem = ItmMst.Item              
    WHERE 
        OrdMst.ID = 'MR' 
        AND OrdMst.TYPE = 'F' 
        AND ItmMst.ItmType IN ('1', '2') 
    ORDER BY 
    OrdMst.OrdItem;

Comment: Can there be multiple `ItmMst` for the same `OrdItem`?  Otherwise, I can't think of any reason why that would change the results.

Comment: I added a note about lazy evaluation and a link to a resource that confirms my understanding of SELECT (at least on Postgres). Perhaps that will explain why you'd see something different in testing.

Comment: Thank you.  I completely agree it is just weird that adding the extra input field it gets a different answer but I guess since it needs the field that it re-evaluates whether it still meets the where clause.

Comment: Charles' answer is about DB2 not MSSQL.

Comment: Nevermind.  Found Declare Cursor syntax and didn't notice that sensitivity is not an option.

Comment: The DB2 documentation for `ibm-midrange` is [here](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_74/db2/rbafzh2dclcu.htm)

Answer (score 2):

I don't see any RPG..

Assuming you are using the posted statement as part of a `DECLARE CURSOR` statement in RPG, then there's additional clauses that control the cursor behavior.

[image: syntax diagram]

From the [documentation](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_72/db2/rbafzh2dclcu.htm)
**ASENSITIVE (The default)**
Specifies that the cursor may behave as SENSITIVE or INSENSITIVE
depending on how the select-statement is optimized.

**SENSITIVE**
Specifies that changes made to the database after the cursor is opened are
visible in the result table. The cursor has some level of sensitivity to any
updates or deletes made to the rows underlying its result table after the
cursor is opened. The cursor is always sensitive to positioned updates or
deletes using the same cursor. Additionally, the cursor can have sensitivity
to changes made outside this cursor. If the database manager cannot make
changes visible to the cursor, then an error is returned. The database
manager cannot make changes visible to the cursor when the cursor
implicitly becomes read-only. (See Result table of a cursor.) If SENSITIVE is
specified, the SELECT statement cannot contain a data-change-table-reference.

**INSENSITIVE**
Specifies that once the cursor is opened, it does not have sensitivity to
inserts, updates, or deletes performed by this or any other activation
group. If INSENSITIVE is specified, the cursor is read-only and a
temporary result is created when the cursor is opened. In addition, the
SELECT statement cannot contain a UPDATE clause and the application
must allow a copy of the data (ALWCPYDTA(*OPTIMIZE) or
ALWCPYDTA(*YES)).